# Blazor - Find Component's Name Using Developer Tools

Tags: .net, angular, debugging, blazor, google-chrome-devtools

I switched from Angular to Blazor recently. In angular, the components are rendered with the `tag`, same as the Component's name in `TS` file. Hence it is easy to find the component in the project. But in case of the **Blazor**, the component is rendered as a `Div` tag.

If I want to find the component's name or path from Chrome's Dev Tools, how can I find it?

I tried creating a sample project and added a component into another component. The element marked with the red in below image is the component. As you can see the component is rendered as a `Div` tag.
[image: Component snap]

How can I get the name of that component?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an id for it.

```
<div id="Foo"/>
```

So you can search it by `Foo` in Chrome's Dev Tools.